# Smfony 6 : How to add a prefix for auto generated URL requesting app.js, app.css, runtime.js, etc

Tags: docker, nginx, url-routing, symfony6

I have an application with symfony i need to deploy with Docker on a server with others applications. I use NginX to redirect on the right Docker container each application by their BASE_URL.

I added a base url (prefix) to my symfony routes and it works. All my routes are prefixed by /test_dev and the routes to my images too.

However, the auto generated request for app.js, app.css, etc. does not take the prefix :
Those request are http://MY_IP/build/app.js
Instead of http://MY_IP/test_dev/app.js

I need this prefix to load those resources.

So, how can i add the prefix for those requests ? I only need this prefix

Thank you